# how to process large file without stack overflow error in haskell?

Tags: haskell

here is my code:(get file line num and word count)

```
import System.IO
import Data.Maybe
readL::(Int,Int,Int)->IO()
readL (w,l,-1) = do
                putStrLn $ "word:" ++(show w )++"\nline:"++(show l)
readL (w,l,0) = do 
                s<-hIsEOF stdin
                if s 
                        then readL (w,l,-1)
                        else 
                                do
                                f<-getLine
                                readL (w+length f,l+1,0)

main = do
        hSetBinaryMode stdin True
        readL (0,0,0)
```

when I process a file with size 100m,it just crashes,with error:
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes

Is there something I wrote wrong?

I also have another version here:

```
import System.IO
import Data.List
main = do
        hSetBinaryMode stdin True
        interact $ (\(w,l)->"line:"++(show l)++"\nwords:"++(show w)++"\n"). foldl' (\(w,l) r-> (w + length r,l+1) ) (0,0)   .lines
```

this have the same problem too... and with lots of memory,so,anybody can slove this?I'm just a new learner in haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that neither the `w` nor the `l` parameter to `readL` are evaluated before the end of input is reached. So for an input with many lines, you build huge thunks `(((0 + length line1) + length line2) ... + length lastline)`, similar for `l`, and for more than half a million lines or so, evaluating that thunk will not fit in the available stack. Additionally, the `length f` holds on to the line read until it is evaluated, causing unnecessarily large memory use.

You have to keep the accumulating parameters evaluated in the loop, the easiest way is with bang-patterns

```
readL !(!w,!l,-1) = ...
```

or a `seq`:

```
readL (w,l,c)
    | w `seq` l `seq` (c == -1) = putStrLn $ "word:" ++(show w )++"\nline:"++(show l)
readL (w,l,0) = do 
                s<-hIsEOF stdin
                if s 
                        then readL (w,l,-1)
                        else 
                                do
                                f<-getLine
                                readL (w+length f,l+1,0)
```

The `foldl'` version has the same problem,

```
foldl' (\(w,l) r-> (w + length r,l+1) ) (0,0)
```

only evaluates the accumulator pair to weak head normal form, that is *to the outermost constructor*, here `(,)`. It does not force evaluation of the components. To do that, you can

- use a strict pair type for the fold

  ```
  data P = P !Int !Int

  foo = ... . foldl' (\(P w l) r -> P (w + length r) (l+1)) (P 0 0) . lines
  ```
- or use `seq` in the folded function

  ```
  ... . foldl' (\(w,l) r -> w `seq` l `seq` (w + length r, l+1)) . lines
  ```

Comment: I added a few words on why the `foldl'` doesn't help.

Comment: Final question,is foldl' version slower than the loop version? I mean,the foldl version will split all lines into memory,and then process it,or, because of the lazy feature,just like pipe in linux,it will act like the loop version?

Comment: The `foldl'` version will take the lines as they come, if the `w` parameter is kept evaluated so that nothing references old lines anymore, they can be garbage collected near immediately, so it doesn't need the entire input in memory at once. It starts processing before the entire input is available. The performance difference, if any, will be very small.

Comment: I made some tests.foldl version is faster than foldl' and faster than the loop version,so I guess that would because of lazy